# Relationship between Heat Flux and Engine RPM

Tags: heat-transfer, engines, research

I'm doing a project that involves knowing the average steady-state heat dissipation rate of a single cylinder air-cooled engine (through the engine wall and fins) at a given RPM. The problem is that I cannot seem to find any research regarding the same. Most of the data available out there revolves around the measurement of the peak heat flux across different components(piston, wall, etc.) at various crank angles.

At this point, even a rough value would be good enough.

Comment: There is or used to be a conference VTMS (Vehicle Thermal Management Systems) that had lots of articles around engine and heat transfer... may be look for that. Run by the IMechE and is still running...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get started with an estimate.

First, start with an e-mail to Briggs & Stratton and ask them. They are the biggest air-cooled engine manufacturer in the US. If anybody knows the answer, it's them.

Otherwise, google on "energy content in automobile engine exhaust". The difference in energy content in the exhaust and energy content of the fuel is the energy content lost by conduction out of the engine itself.

Comment: (Minus the actual shaft work)  :)